# Check Aui form with javascript function before aui Validator in Liferay

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have this form.

```
<aui:form action="<%=addRequestURL%>" method="post" name="fm" >
            <!-- aui:input fields --> 
            // aui:validator


            <!-- input fields -->
           //validation with a function (jQuery)

    <aui:button id="checkFields" value="submit" type="submit" disabled="<%=fieldsDisabled %>"/>
</aui:form>
```

And I'm using Aui Validators to validate the fields.

And then, I have a javascript function :

```
<aui:script use="aui-base">
jQuery(function($) {    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkFields").click(function(){

        var result1=A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>FieldA").get("value");
        var result2=A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>FieldAFieldB").get("value");

        if (result1< result2){ 
           alert('I will not submit');
          //Not Submit the Form
           return false;}

        });
    }); 
});
</aui:script>
```

I just have to check the result of the the JavaScript function before to submit the form and before validation.
If this function return false, the form submission will not be executed.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps You can use aui custom validator , have a look at https://rajeevalochanabr.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/aui-form-validation-using-aui-validation-tag-liberary/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that a have some aui:input fields and other  input ( not aui) and I have to validate them all when submit. I need to prevent submission when aui:input fields are ok. And to submit the form only when aui:input ans other input fields ( jQuery check ) are ok.

Comment: Are you getting into this validation method? The click would not be working as aui:button id (checkFields) appends namesapce with it.

Comment: Try using $('#<portlet:namespace />checkFields').click(function()